# Laravel - How to redirect after ajax form post submission in controller?

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 5.1, I want to redirect to home page after the user is logged in. I have used ajax for submitting form via post request but after the user is authenticated using the Auth middleware. How can I redirect user to home page from the controller ? I can use jquery for redirecting but I want to do it from controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending the credentials via Ajax then you should redirect the location by using JavaScript. Server can't redirect the window to a new location in this case.

Comment: ok, Yes I have redirected using javascript, if you saying I cant do it from server end in this case. Can you tell how can I active the sessions in laravel ? As I am using Auth middleware .

Comment: @Calvin I think laravel enables sessions by default. You can modify the settings in the `sessions.php` file: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/session.php